# Applying the Poisson Distribution to problems

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The number of traffic accidents at a certain intersection is thought to be well modeled by a Poisson process with a mean of $3$ accidents per year.

Find the probability that more than one year elapses between accidents.

I am not really sure if I am doing this problem correctly but here was my attempt.

I know that the expected value is $3$ accidents per year, and I have to find the probability that more than one year elapses between accidents.

$P(X > 1)=1-P(X \le 1)$

$P(X>1)=1-[P(X=0)+P(X=1)]$

$P(X>1)=1-[\dfrac{e^{-3}*3^{0}}{0!} + \dfrac{e^{-3}*3^{1}}{1!}]$

$P(X>1)=0.8$

Is this the correct way to solve this problem? This problem is very different from the examples in my textbook where they ask for the number of $x$ accidents that occur instead of time elapsing between accidents.

***Update**
I see that $P(X=0)$ is equivalent to more than one year elapses between accidents.

The second part of the questions asks me to find the probability that less than once month elapses between accidents.

Since the unit of time changed from 1 year to 1 month, I divided the expected value by $12$ and got $\mu = 3/12$. I think that the probability that less than one month elapses between accidents would be equal to $P(X=1)$. This gives

$P(X=1) = \dfrac{e^{-1}*1^{3/12}}{1!} = 0.368$.

Is that correct?

Comment: We want the probability of $0$ accidents in $1$ year. That is a familiar calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are being asked for the probability of $0$ accidents in $1$ year. That is a problem you know how to solve. The probability of no accidents in the period from now to a year from now is the probability that $Y=0$, where $Y$ is a random variable with Poisson distribution, parameter $3$.

**Remark:** More generally, if the number of accidents in a specified time period has Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$, then the waiting time between accidents has exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$. For the number of accidents in a period of time $t$ has Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda t$.

**Added:** For the added question about a month, let $W$ be the number of accidents in a month. This has Poisson distribution with parameter $\frac{3}{12}$. So the probability more than a month elapses with no accident is $e^{-3/12}$. The probability that *less* than a month elapses is $1-e^{-3/12}$.

Comment: I have tried that but having a expected value of $0$ would make the entire probability $0$ and I don't think that's correct.

Comment: At any time, the probability that more than one year elapses before the next accident is $e^{-3}$.

Comment: I have edited my original post with the second part of my question. Could you take a look at it to see if I did this correctly?

Comment: Because typing in comments is difficult, I have added an answer to your added question below the main answer.

Comment: I know my numbers are wrong for the second part I have added, but would it be possible to calculate the probability without first finding that a month elapses with no accident occurring?

Comment: The "more" and "less" problems are close relatives. We could also have used the Remark I made about the waiting time between accidents having exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$. So the probability that the waiting time is $\le t$ is $1-e^{-\lambda t}$. Put $t=1/12$.